# What other member should I use besides `isSuccess` when making a get request with Alamofire?

Tags: swift, error-handling, httprequest, alamofire

I'm trying to make a get request with Alamofire. I'm getting an error that says "value of type 'Result' has no member 'isSuccess'". This is my code:

```
func getWeatherData (url: String, parameters: [String : String]) {
        AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters : parameters).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {

        }
        else {

        }
        }
    }
```

How should I make the `if` statement work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hi marcus,
You can check the success by using switch statement also you can access the JSON response.

```
func getWeatherData (url: String, parameters: [String : String]) {
    AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters : parameters).responseJSON {
    response in

    switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            success(data) // data is actual response from API
        case .failure(let error):
            failure(error.localizedDescription) 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
func getWeatherData (url: String, parameters: [String : String]) {
    AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters : parameters).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        //Success
    case .failure:
        //Failure
    }
}
```